# How to open a Webi report from Design Studio?

Tags: business-objects, webi

We have recently installed Design Studio 1.5 and trying to call existing Webi reports through Design Studio.

Can anyone please let me know the steps involved to attain this?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use the OpenDocument feature.

Have a look at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com) which contains all the manuals for SAP products. Specifically [this page](http://help.sap.com/bobip?current=pcat_analytics&show_children=false) contains the OpenDocument manuals (search the page for `OpenDocument` and select the version corresponding to your BI4 deployment).

In a nutshell (you can find all the information you need in the aforementioned manuals): the OpenDocument feature is basically a URL in which you provide the necessary parameters (docID, parameters, …) to open and optionally refresh your report. As it's a URL, you can embed it just about anywhere (an HTML page, a Design Studio app, … even another Webi document!).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the OpenDocument URL of the Webi report, you can use the scripting function `APPLICATION.openNewWindow(newUrl)` in the Design Studio client, and pass in the URL. As Kristof suggested, check on SCN where there are many users writing guides and discussions on how to get the URL.